# How can I rectify an improper upgrade to v 22.04?

Tags: boot, upgrade, 22.04

I was in the process of upgrading Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 via this command (*sudo do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3*). However, during the installation and upgrade process, I frequently saw messages such as "JellyFish is not responding" etc. and a pop up asking me to Wait or Quit.

I clicked on 'Wait' several times, but kept seeing the same message again. Finally, I chose 'Quit' and the installation stopped. But my system got upgraded to 22.04 anyways. I verified this via the *lsb_release -a* command.

Afterwards, I restarted my machine and saw this message during startup.
[image]

I always see this message when I boot my machine. I also see some gibberish when I shut down. These messages were not appearing with the previous Ubuntu version. Therefore, I deduce this is most likely due to the new installation not completing successfully.

Is there any way I can ensure that the installation completes successfully and this message is not shown when I boot?

Answer (score 4):

Those are kernel notification about minor hardware irritations. That's what the kernel does: It manages interface with hardware. Both messages are harmless, you cannot get rid of them easily, and they are NOT likely due to some kind of botched release-upgrade.

To test if your release-upgrade is complete:

1. Review your apt sources in /etc/apt/sources.list. The correct release name (like "jammy" for 22.04) should be listed on each deb line. The old release name (like "focal" for 20.04) should NOT be listed.

Example:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
// 22.04 = jammy. Good.
```

2. Once #1 above is complete, run `sudo apt update`. It should complete without any errors. Next, run `sudo apt full-upgrade`. It should also complete without any errors. Finally, run `sudo snap refresh`.
3. Run `apt-cache madison linux-image-generic` to see which kernel your current system *should* be running (5.15, 5.4, 4.18. 4.6, etc.) Compare that to the version of your currently running kernel (`uname -r`)

Example:

```
   $ apt-cache madison linux-image-generic
linux-image-generic | 5.15.0.40.42 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-generic | 5.15.0.39.40 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
   $ uname -r
5.15.0-39-generic
// 5.15 matches the current kernel from linux-image-generic. Good.
```